# ограничить время выполнения функции node.js

Tags: node.js

Есть функция:

```
function go(domain) {
scrape(options, (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log('FAIL');
    }
    else {
      updateStatus(domain['id'], 2);
      console.log('SUCCES');
    }
    getFreeDomainsAndGo();
});
}
```

при условии, что функция `go` работает больше 60мин., нужно завершить ее выполнение и вызвать `getFreeDomainsAndGo()`.

Comment: Гадаю по фото: функция go у вас работает быстро. Полагаю, что долго работает scrape. Если эту функцию писали не вы, то есть вероятность, что автор предусмотрел таймауты

Comment: Да действительно, есть параметр `timeout`, который ограничивает кол-во секунд на запрос. По истечении указанного времени, как я понял, будет вызван `callback` и в `error` вы получите ошибку `timeout`